# Making list items horizontal no line break even in smalll screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a gallery view using an Unordered list. With a large screen:

[image: Large screen doesn't cause wrap]

With a small screen it will wrap like this:

[image]

How can I hide any content that overflows over 1 line?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl" class="container-fluid ng-scope" style="
        display: inline;
    ">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;display: inline;"><!-- ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">12 Aug 
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display: block;width:56px;height:56px;">13 Aug
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">14 Aug 
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">15 Aug 
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">16 Aug 
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;float: left;clear: both;">17 Aug 
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">18 Aug
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
        <li ng-repeat="location in forecasts" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            <img src="/images/Sunny-icon.png" style="display:block;width:56px;height:56px;">19 Aug
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: location in forecasts -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query for a small desktop e.g : 500px, give a fixed height with overflow:hidden to hide, here my code : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8fmsdu/2/)

My css :

```
    @media screen and (max-width:500px) { /* media query for screen
    with maximum width of 500px */
        div[ng-controller=TypeaheadCtrl] { /* parent div height is
    fixed to 70px so other line is hidden */
            height: 70px; /* image + text */
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }

    div[ng-controller=TypeaheadCtrl] > ul { /* > is for the first ul child for div,
    if you gonna have an ul in a first ul, this rule don't gonna apply */
        font-size: 0; /* hack for remove spacing for inline-block */
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    div[ng-controller=TypeaheadCtrl] li {
        font-size: 12px; /* add font-size again for li */
        display: inline-block;
    }

    div[ng-controller=TypeaheadCtrl] li > img {
        display:block;
        width:56px;
        height:56px;
    }
```

I've removed all inline style from your html too, it's easier to maintain.
Hope it's what you want